# How can I calculate % of 1's each row in asp gridview and display inside template field label?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with 8 columns:

user|%|a|b|c|d|e|f

JJJJ|%|1|0|0|1|1|1

AAA|%|1|1|1|1|1|0

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
runat="server"  OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="text" runat="server" Text="%"></asp:Label>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="myLabel" Text="%" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="a" HeaderText="a" >
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="b" HeaderText="b"> 
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="c" HeaderText="c"  >
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="d" HeaderText="d"   >
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="e" HeaderText="e" >
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="f" HeaderText="f" >
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

The a-f columns have bit data type pulled from SQL database (True and False).
I added a template field with an asp Label to display the % column that I would like to get the percentage of 1's for each row but can't figure out how to calculate this and display in the label. So I want to calculate the percentage of times the value 1 shows up per row and display it in that rows label.

I can get to the label by this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            (Label)e.Row.FindControl("mylabel") = (The Percentage of 1's counted by row);
       }
    }
```

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop all the cells in the RowDataBound event and check the data source for `1` values and calculate the percentage.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the row back to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        decimal NoOfOnes = 0;
        decimal NoOfColumns = e.Row.Cells.Count - 1;

        //loop all the columns and find the 1's
        for (int i = 0; i < NoOfColumns; i++)
        {
            if (row[i].ToString() == "1")
            {
                NoOfOnes++;
            }
        }

        //find the label in the current row
        Label lbl = e.Row.FindControl("myLabel") as Label;

        //display results
        lbl.Text = string.Format("{0:N2}", (NoOfOnes / NoOfColumns) * 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course, the number of columns is fixed, so you have to make cross multiplication:
6 columns = 100%
4 columns = x%
In order to do that, you can use an iterator to add and know the number of 1's in your register.
Something like that:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int countTrues = 0;
        //i = 1 because your first column is dispensable to this.
        for (int i = 1; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(e.Row.Cells[i].Text))
            {
                //If you get 1 from the database, it will convert to true, so it will increment the counter.
                countTrues++;
            }
        }

        //The amount of "trues" multiplied by 100 divided by 6 which is the number of columns you have.
        ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("mylabel")).Text = ((countTrues * 100) / 6).ToString();
   }
}
```

And then you get this:
[image: Number of 1's calculated]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting the following error.  String was not recognized as a valid Boolean on this line if (Convert.ToBoolean(e.Row.Cells[i].Text)).  Is this because in the gridview I have a case statement to make the "True" values display 1?